# PHP Templating Preg_Replace

Tags: php, templates

I'm making a simple templating system in php.

If I have a variable called $var, I want [var] to be replaced with the value of $var. But I want it to work with anything in square brackets. Could anyone give me a Preg_Replace for this?

Comment: no write your own code, no don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Have a look into `preg_replace_callback`. Try something, then come back and we can help.

Comment: I don't know anything about Preg_Replace. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @ConnorGurney what best examples than the documentation and a website dedicated to regexp? You need to make some efforts, or you'll be help-dependent. You know, give a man a fish...

Comment: I've got the following code so far. <?php
function text2bbc($text){
    $find = array(
        '~\[(.*?)\]~s',
    );
    $replace = array(
        '$$1',
    );
    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}

$var='var';
echo '[var]'; ?>, but it replaces [var] with $[var]. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Althought NOT a solution, you might want to start with:

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

And then read:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Have fun